# How to make KeyboardState not blow through switch statement with state machine?

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

The question is phrased very oddly, and for that I apologize. I am trying to create a little game and I'm having a hard time with a statemachine.

**Enumeration Type**

```
public enum Phase
{
    FirstPhase,
    SecondPhase,
    ThirdPhase,
    FourthPhase;
};
```

**Code**

```
public Phase currentPhase = Phase.FirstPhase;

public KeyboardState keyboardState;

public KeyboardState oldKeyboardState;

void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    oldKeyboardState = keyboardState;
    keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

    switch (currentPhase)
    {
        case FirstPhase:

            //just throws the phase to be secondPhase
            currentPhase = Phase.SecondPhase;

            break;

        case SecondPhase:
            //wait for input

            if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter) && oldKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Enter))
            {
                currentPhase = Phase.ThirdPhase;
            }
            break;

        case ThirdPhase:
            //do some calculation stuff, decide on something, etc.
            if (keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter) && oldKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Enter))
            {
                currentPhase = Phase.FourthPhase;
            }
            break;

        case FourthPhase:

            //end of phases, exit or do nothing, etc.
            break;
    }
}
```

The problem happens when `SecondPhase` goes into third phase, it seems to always want to skip `ThirdPhase` and go straight to `FourthPhase` because enter is still being held pressed, but I thought in the switch it should only do one "phase" maximum in the one call of `Update`, so you should not go to `FourthPhase` until you press enter *again*?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: try not to mix `switch` and `if/else` statements, it's confusing.

Comment: How should I be doing it then?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to flip around the key up / down logic.

```
if (keyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Enter) && oldKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter)) 
{ 
     currentPhase = Phase.ThirdPhase; 
}
```

This should have the effect of only changing states when the user releases the enter key after pressing it.

It'll have a slightly different "feel" to the input but if you can live with that it's a nice simple solution.